# Determine the point $a$ such that the given function is invertible in the vicinity of $a$

Tags: calculus

I try to understand the Inverse Function theorem, but I'm still got some confusion. Here is the function.

$f(x,y,z)=(x+e^y,y+e^z,z+e^x )$

It’s easy to see that $f$ is defined on $\mathbb R^3$.

Now we find the matrix $Df(x,y,z)$

$Df(x,y,z)= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & e^y & 0 \\
0 & 1 & e^z \\
e^x & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right) $

Again this is 3 continuous functions.

We need to show that $Df(x,y,z)$ is bijective.$ Df$ is bijective if $det⁡(Df)≠0$

$det⁡(Df)=1+e^{x+y+z}≠0$

$e^{x+y+z}≠-1$ which is true for all $x,y,z \in \mathbb R$

So if $c∈A= \mathbb R^3$, then $Df(c)$ is bijective and there exist an open ball $B(c)$. Let $c=(0,0,0)$ and $B(c)=B_{1/2} (0,0,0)$

This is where I'm stuck. What do I do next? This section was taught by one of my classmate, so I may have alot of stupid question because of confusion.

Comment: What do you *want* do next? You have proved that $f$ is locally invertible near of any $(x,y,z)=c\in\Bbb R^3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're overthinking the problem. The inverse function theorem states that if $f$ is continuously differentiable and $Df(a)$ has full rank at a point $a$ in the domain of $f$, then $f$ is invertible on a neighborhood of $a$.

You've shown that $Df$ has nonzero determinant, and hence full rank, at *every* point $a$ in the domain of $f$. Once you also check that $f$ is continuously differentiable everywhere (which is "obvious"), you are done: by the inverse function theorem $f$ is invertible on a neighborhood of $a$ for every $a\in \mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Oh, I though I need to check all the property of the ball contain $c$, but I realize that if I do so, i just get back to the starting point. Thanks.